# Issue with plotting in MATLAB (using ode45)

Tags: matlab

Alright so i want to plot the right side as a function of N using this equation:

```
dN/dt=-0.5N+100
```

I'm using MATLAB and my problem is that the plot stops at an `x` value of `200`.

I'm using the following code:

```
T = 1000;

eq = @(t,N)(-0.5*N+100);

[t,N] = ode45(eq,[0 500],-5);

plot(N,-0.5*N+100)

axis([0 1000 -500 500])
```

Is there any way I can get my graph to continue to an `x` value of `1000`?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're only solving the ode on the interval `[0 500]` (see the second argument you pass to the `ode45` function). To plot it on a different interval, you first need to solve it on a different interval:

```
T = 1000;
eq = @(t,N)(-0.5*N+100);
[t,N] = ode45(eq,[0 1000],-5); % second argument changed to solve on different interval
plot(N,-0.5*N+100)
axis([0 1000 -500 500])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `N` converges to `200` after some time, as you can see the plot below:
[image]

So there will be no value more than 200 and when you want to plot dN/dt vs. N your x axis will be from 0 to 200.